# inner join sales and products

Tags: sql, inner-join

hi i am having a problem with an inner join  on my products and sales table i need to display a list of all the sales and also list  the products which havn't been selling

this is the cod i have been trying-->

```
SELECT
products.prod_id, 
       products.prod_name, 
       sales.date_of_sale, 


    FROM 
       products
    INNER JOIN 
       sales
    ON 
       products.prod_id = sales.prod_id;
```

here is a picture of products table 
[image: products]

here is a picture of the sales table

[image: sales table]

any help would be greatly appreciated.. thank you very much ..

Comment: Whats the issue?  Need to see products without sales?  use a left join instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the product and its sales

```
SELECT products.prod_id,
       products.prod_name,
       sales.date_of_sale
FROM   products
       INNER JOIN sales
               ON products.prod_id = sales.prod_id;
```

To display products which don't have sales

```
SELECT products.prod_id,
       products.prod_name
FROM   products
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   sales
                   WHERE  products.prod_id = sales.prod_id);
```

If you want select in a single query

```
SELECT products.prod_id,
       products.prod_name,
       sales.date_of_sale
FROM   products
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sales
                    ON products.prod_id = sales.prod_id;
```